# Creating a mutex class using Allegro mutexes

Tags: c++, mutex, allegro

I'm trying to create a custom mutex class based on the Allegro mutex (cross-platform). I am *not* using C++11. I'm trying to do it like this, but it seems to be a bit superfluous:

```
template <class T>
class Mutex
  {

  private:
  ALLEGRO_MUTEX *mutex = NULL;
  ALLEGRO_THREAD *owner = NULL;
  T *data = NULL;

  public:
  Mutex ();
  Mutex (T* data);
  ~Mutex ();
  bool lock (ALLEGRO_THREAD* thread);
  bool unlock (ALLEGRO_THREAD* thread);
  bool trylock (); //Returns true if you can lock the thread
  bool set (T* data, ALLEGRO_THREAD* thread);
  bool get (T** data, ALLEGRO_THREAD* thread); //Pass reference of pointer

  }
```

The constructors will call `al_create_mutex()` and, in the case of the second one, set the data pointer. The destructor calls `al_destroy_mutex()`.

The lock method will check to see if `owner` is `NULL` (indicating the mutex is unlocked and no thread owns it). If it is `NULL`, then it will set `owner = thread` and lock the mutex. The unlock method unlocks the mutex if `thread == owner` and sets `owner = NULL`.

The trylock method simply checks to see if `owner == NULL`, indicating that the mutex is not locked by any thread.

The `set` and `get` methods will set and return the stored pointer, only if the calling thread is the owner of the locked mutex.

I have a feeling that i'm going a bit overboard with the whole passing the thread every time you want to call a method, but i don't see any other way to make this class thread-safe, since Allegro doesn't have a `al_get_current_thread()` function or something like that. What should i do with this class?

Comment: You have initializers for non-static class members - you are in fact using C++11. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest that you create a class that only wraps the Allegro mutex functionality, and does nothing else. Then make a separate template class that uses a mutex to provide exclusive access to a datum.

Your accesses to `Mutex::owner` require synchronization to avoid data races. If you really want to provide recursive and/or trylock behavior, do that in a separate class or classes that use your basic mutex in their implementation. (Hint: use one mutex to protect the `owner` field and another to provide the actual mutual exclusion to clients).

I suspect that a basic RAII wrapper without the `ALLEGRO_THREAD` arguments is all you will really end up needing.